# Angular js directive attribute not being attached to directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to pass and argument to a directive via element attributes
below is a snippet:

**directive**

```
app.directive('bgFluct', function(){
  var _ = {};
  _.scope = {
    data: "@ngData"
  }
  _.link = function(scope, elem, attr) {

    // if there is no image provided use pp.png the default
       scope.background = scope.data !== undefined ? scope.data : '../../img/pp.png'
    elem.css(
      {
        'background': 'url('+scope.background+')',
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        'background-position': 'center center'
      })
  }
  return _;
})
```

**html**

```
<div class="four columns" style="margin-right: 20px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-data="{{ vm.background_image }}" class="project-item" bg-fluct>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my directive `console.log(scope)` prints:

[image: scope has a data property but i cant access it by scope.data]

The **main problem** is `scope` has a data property (screenshot below) but I can't access it by `scope.data`

I have looked over my entire code again and again but still cant find a solution to this problem.

How can I go about accessing the `ng-data` property from the directive attribute ?

Cheers!

Comment: I think you should have `scope.background = scope.data !== undefined ? scope.data : '../../img/pp.png'`

Comment: @PankajParkar Already tried that, the thing is that scope.data is always undefined or empty even though in my html i do `<div ng-data="{{ vm.background_image }}" class="project-item" bg-fluct>` for sure `vm.background_image` has a value

Comment: is it the case that you are setting value of `background_image ` from ajax? but still console.log is showing value of `data` in directive scope

Comment: @PankajParkar correct!

Comment: The value of ``data`` is not yet present, while initializing the directive. You could wait with initializing this directive until the value is there (e.g. ``ng-if="valueIsAvailable``) or just ``$scope.$watch`` the passed value and as soon it is another value, change the variable. Another way is to just access the passed variable in the view.

Comment: Did you try this <div ng-data="vm.background_image" class="project-item" bg-fluct>  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution to your issue is to use $timeout, by wrapping your code in a timeout you give the digest loop the time to execute and initialize your attribute:

```
$timeout(function() {
    scope.background = scope.data !== undefined ? scope.data : '../../img/pp.png'
    elem.css(
      {
        'background': 'url('+scope.background+')',
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        'background-position': 'center center'
      });
}, 0); // <== 0 timeout or some if it didn't work
```

Another solution maybe to register a watcher on your attribute:

```
scope.$watch('data', function(data){/* the same as the previous example */})
```

Comment: Dang it, you beat me to it! I realised the problem was that I was making a call to a service which was asynchronous. So the first time when the directive is initialised, data is always undefined. Nevertheless,Thank you so much!!! :D :D